# How do you create portable databases with MsBuild?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sqlite, msbuild, portable-database

I want to store in my solution a project containing the database creation scripts.
When this project is built, it must generate a database file, which will then be used by this and other projects of the solution at the run time.
How to do that?

I know I can add Pre-Build task, but I wonder:

- which command line can help me (maybe sqlite has a command line client?)
- will it need that I create an empty database file before running the scripts?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846013/how-can-i-execute-sqlite-sqlite3-statements-in-msbuild-the-exec-task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the command line client shell for SQLite at http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Then you can add the following Pre-Build task:

```
"sqlite3.exe" %dbFilename% < Database.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

try Access db(extension: accdb)...its easy to edit and can be backed up and used with Office access..as well.also its portable..