# How can i execute sqlite (sqlite3) statements in MSBUILD, the Exec Task?

Tags: sqlite, msbuild

I am trying to run some queries on my sqlite database after building my application.

I have tried;

```
<Exec Command='sqlite3 "@(DeployedSqliteDbPath) DELETE FROM BatchConfig";'/>
```

and

```
<Exec Command='sqlite3 "@(DeployedSqliteDbPath)";'/>
<Exec Command='sqlite3 "DELETE FROM BatchConfig";'/>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995597/how-do-you-use-portable-databases-with-msbuild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked;

```
<Exec Command='sqlite3 "@(DeployedSqliteDbPath)" "DELETE FROM BatchConfig;"'/>
```